# Vegan dinosaur runs prefect jobs

Tags: python-3.x, logging, prefect

I'm using python's `prefect` library (2.7.9) for managing complex cron-task flows. My library log:
[image: dino manages workflow]

It is wierd, but:

1. Why does **vegan dinosaur** run my prefect tasks?
2. Are there any **fundamental principles** on using prehistoric animals for task management?
3. What **else** can be used and what are the **trade-offs** of using/not using carnism-ones?

Comment: Restarted the task and faithful-panther finished the flow successfully. So, meat matters

Comment: Realized, it was actually a tank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is how we call Prefect flow runs - it's always a random combination of an adjective (like vegan) and an animal name/type (dinosaur)
2. No lol
3. We have an open issue for that https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/7463 and there is a workaround here https://gist.github.com/crscheid/10dbf291779667831b856fab9cc9745b

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was a joke, but thanks anyway.